# DataColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = -1

Tags: ado.net

What does it means if AutoIncrementSeed property has value -1  ?

Answer (score 1):

This means the new ids will start being allocated from the number -1.  If it is coupled with an auto increment step of -1, the new IDs will decrease: ie, -1, -2, -3, etc.  This is valuable for allocating IDs in a dataset before the dataset is saved to the actual database - the negative numbers help you easily identify unsaved records and can be automatically updated with positive IDs after the save.

Hope this helps,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

The schema of sql server table along with the data, couldn't override the AutoNumber Increment.

have to take this code out

```
Adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
```